# What is the difference between host and client ssh key generation?

Tags: ssh, key-generation

Having read the ssh-keygen man page, i saw the '-h' flag and the following:

> ssh-keygen supports two types of certificates: user and host.  User
>   certificates authenticate users to servers, whereas host certificates
>   authenticate server hosts to users

I understand the server/client usage, the different storage locations and the certificates are unique, but is there a fundamentally difference?

I.e. If I don't use the '-h' flag during host key generation, have I made an error that could cause issues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSH: What's the difference or interplay between /etc/ssh/\[host files\] and ~/.ssh/\[public key\]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/86981/ssh-whats-the-difference-or-interplay-between-etc-ssh-host-files-and-ssh)

Comment: Had put together an answer, then saw @gowenfawr 's comment. I'd say that it is a duplicate and the link they posted holds the answer for the OP.

Comment: I'd say it's not exactly a duplicate, as the linked question asks what the difference between both files is, while this question asks if you can use them interchangably.

Comment: Retracting my close vote because @MechMK1 came up with an answer that succinctly, differently, and validly answers this question as opposed to the possible dupe.  Kudos :)

Comment: Another fair comment from @MechMK1, as I was reading more the spirit of the question rather than the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

According to the source code of [openssh-portable](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable), the `-h` flag modifies the certificate type and selects permitted options to None.

Here is the [relevant source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh-keygen.c):

```
/* Key type when certifying */
static u_int cert_key_type = SSH2_CERT_TYPE_USER; // L105

/* If -h is set, set certificate type to Host and set cert flags to none. */
case 'h': // L2573
    cert_key_type = SSH2_CERT_TYPE_HOST;
    certflags_flags = 0;
    break;

/* Set the certificate type to whatever value was set before */
public->cert->type = cert_key_type; // L1744
```

As you can see, that's all the magic. <s>If you used the wrong certificate type, then the verifying end will refuse to accept the certificate, as it was not signed for that purpose. You can't use a client certificate to identify as server, and you can't use a server certificate to authenticate as client. You *can* however use the same key to create both a client and a server certificate.</s>

As it turns out, you can indeed use a client certificate for purposes of host identification, and vice versa. This seems to me like a bug.

Comment: I've looked deeper based on your info and did some testing, the certs are interchangeable but host certs disable some functions such as port forwarding (L118 & L1583). My 1st post, so don't want to cause trouble editing your answer with a slightly different answer that you may not agree with.

Comment: @PAihGKy0W No no, feel free to edit or downvote if it is wrong. I'm glad I could send you into the right direction, even if my conclusion was wrong. It just seems...odd that openssh would allow a client certificate being used as a host certificate. Seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Agreed, never thought to sudo ssh -i <host key location>, but it works.

Comment: @PAihGKy0W You should open a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hint @MechMK1. It looks like the certificates as interchangeable from my testing, but client certificates have more functionality.

It seems to control the following areas:

```
/* Certificate options */
#define CERTOPT_X_FWD   (1) // L118
#define CERTOPT_AGENT_FWD   (1<<1)
#define CERTOPT_PORT_FWD    (1<<2)
#define CERTOPT_PTY     (1<<3)
#define CERTOPT_USER_RC (1<<4)
#define CERTOPT_DEFAULT (CERTOPT_X_FWD|CERTOPT_AGENT_FWD| \
         CERTOPT_PORT_FWD|CERTOPT_PTY|CERTOPT_USER_RC)
static u_int32_t certflags_flags = CERTOPT_DEFAULT;

if ((which & OPTIONS_EXTENSIONS) != 0 && // L1583
    (certflags_flags & CERTOPT_X_FWD) != 0)
    add_flag_option(c, "permit-X11-forwarding");
if ((which & OPTIONS_EXTENSIONS) != 0 &&
    (certflags_flags & CERTOPT_AGENT_FWD) != 0)
    add_flag_option(c, "permit-agent-forwarding");
if ((which & OPTIONS_EXTENSIONS) != 0 &&
    (certflags_flags & CERTOPT_PORT_FWD) != 0)
    add_flag_option(c, "permit-port-forwarding");
if ((which & OPTIONS_EXTENSIONS) != 0 &&
    (certflags_flags & CERTOPT_PTY) != 0)
    add_flag_option(c, "permit-pty");
if ((which & OPTIONS_EXTENSIONS) != 0 &&
    (certflags_flags & CERTOPT_USER_RC) != 0)
    add_flag_option(c, "permit-user-rc");
```

A host certificate would disable the above options, limiting those functions to user certificates only.

This is a bit deep for me, but that's how I currently see it.